# Invoke-WebRequest can't download properly

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I was using **Invoke-WebRequest** for some time in my script and today first time I got problem with it - once I run script, it starts to download ZIP file and finishes without warnings, but when I am trying to open file, WinRar gives me an error and I can see that file size is less than it should be. I tried several time and got same result. Then I tried to download file with Google Chrome just to ensure that file is not corrupted, but it downloaded (with correct file size) and opened without any issues.

After couple of hours I ran script again and it downloaded file as well. So now I am not sure that I can trust Invoke-WebRequest since it seems that sometimes it can make incomplete download.

Myabe someone can point me on how I can avoid this situation? Or maybe better to use another method?

Comment: Perhaps you simply had networking problems then, but without seeing any of your code it is impossible to tell

Comment: THe code is quite simple for Invoke_WebRequest:
**Invoke-WebRequest** `https://www.example.com/publicdocs/path/path/2022/08/filename.CSV.zip -OutFile C:\path2\path2\filename.CSV.zip`